# Google CSE animated image search (API)

Tags: bash, search, google-search-api

I want to implement animated image search in my application, so I registered at Google Custom Search engine. As for web search and image search everything is good.
But it appears that animated type image search doesn't work, because Google SCE API haven't "animated" flag.

Edit1: I can filter results by "gif" files only, but result list contains animated and non-animated gif files. I need animated files only.

Comment: Have you tried splitting all the frames of .GIF and sending them one by one? I dont think google will search a .GIF file for you but maybe you can look for all embedded .GIF files in the related websites which are returned by the result.

Comment: I've edited my question, the case not in results, but rather the query parameters